How can I improve NSView rendering performance?
On OS X/Cocoa I have an NSView into which I am drawing an image (when prompted in the drawRect: method). The image is a video camera image that I update around 80 times/second. As measured using Instruments, the actual work in drawRect is relatively fast, as I would hope (330ms for 500 redraws). However, much more time (1-2 seconds) is being spent in CoreAnimation code (a deep function tree involving functions such as CA::Transaction::commit(), GC::DisplayListExecutor::drawImage, ripc_DrawImage, img_raw_read).
It seems that the drawing I am doing from drawRect is only going into some temporary image buffer (of the correct size according to the current window size), and then there is some additional layer of CoreAnimation processing I don't have direct control over, which is taking up the majority of the CPU time. If the function names deep in the call tree are correct, it seems to be doing resampling - e.g. argb32_sample_ARGB32().
I haven't knowingly applied any weird settings to the NSView, and I would expect that what I draw in my drawRect: method should be able to be memcpy'd directly to the screen buffer. That's clearly not happening.
I should say that this is ~10 year old code and .xib, so it's possible there's something old-fashioned in the way it is set up. I don't know where to look, though.
Can anyone advise what I might be missing, or what I could do to debug this situation better?
Edit: I notice that CGColorTransformConvertUsingCMSConverter is in the call tree (see below for full call tree). This is making me wonder if the underlying issue may be related to some sort of mismatch between color spaces. I know very little about color spaces, except that I specified NSDeviceRGBColorSpace in the NSBitmapImageRep that I draw in the NSView. But no issues seem to arise at that stage - the conversion is happening at some lower level outside my control, where my NSView seems to be being redrawn as part of a CoreAnimation layer. I have no idea how to control any mismatch in color space between the NSView and what CoreAnimation expects!
1.20 s   45.0%  0 s                     CA::Transaction::commit()
1.09 s   40.8%  0 s                      CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
1.04 s   39.0%  0 s                       CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
899.00 ms   33.6%   0 s                        -[_NSViewBackingLayer display]
892.00 ms   33.3%   0 s                         -[_NSBackingLayer display]
890.00 ms   33.2%   0 s                          -[CALayer _display]
880.00 ms   32.9%   0 s                           invocation function for block in CA::Layer::display_()
880.00 ms   32.9%   0 s                            CABackingStoreUpdate_
867.00 ms   32.4%   0 s                             -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:]
799.00 ms   29.8%   0 s                              CGDisplayListDrawInContextDelegate
798.00 ms   29.8%   0 s                               CG::DisplayList::execute(CGContextDelegate*, CGRenderingState*, CGGStack*, CGRect const*, __CFDictionary const*)
798.00 ms   29.8%   0 s                                CG::DisplayList::executeEntries(std::__1::__wrap_iter<std::__1::unique_ptr<CG::DisplayListEntry const, std::__1::default_delete<CG::DisplayListEntry const> >*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<std::__1::unique_ptr<CG::DisplayListEntry const, std::__1::default_delete<CG::DisplayListEntry const> >*>, CGContextDelegate*, CGRenderingState*, CGGStack*, CGRect const*, __CFDictionary const*, bool)
798.00 ms   29.8%   0 s                                 CG::DisplayListExecutor::drawImage(CG::DisplayListEntryImage const*)
797.00 ms   29.8%   0 s                                  ripc_DrawImage
498.00 ms   18.6%   0 s                                   ripc_AcquireRIPImageData
498.00 ms   18.6%   0 s                                    RIPImageCacheGetRetained
483.00 ms   18.0%   0 s                                     RIPImageDataInitializeShared
482.00 ms   18.0%   0 s                                      CGSImageDataLock
471.00 ms   17.6%   0 s                                       img_data_lock
464.00 ms   17.3%   0 s                                        img_raw_read
463.00 ms   17.3%   0 s                                         get_chunks_direct
461.00 ms   17.2%   0 s                                          CGDataProviderDirectGetBytesAtPositionInternal
446.00 ms   16.6%   0 s                                           provider_for_destination_get_bytes_at_position_inner
380.00 ms   14.2%   0 s                                            CGColorTransformConvertUsingCMSConverter
369.00 ms   13.8%   0 s                                             convert_using_vImageConverter
355.00 ms   13.2%   0 s                                              vImageConverterConvert
352.00 ms   13.1%   0 s                                               vImageConverter_convert_internal
341.00 ms   12.7%   0 s                                                vImageConvert_AnyToAny
269.00 ms   10.0%   0 s                                                 AnyToAnyBlock
252.00 ms    9.4%   0 s                                                  AnyToAnyBlockInternal
128.00 ms    4.7%   0 s                                                   AnyToAnyBlockInternal
45.00 ms    1.6%    45.00 ms                                                       vUnpremultiplyData_ARGB8888_CV_sse4_1
32.00 ms    1.1%    32.00 ms                                                       vConvert_Planar16Q12toARGB8888_sse4_1
18.00 ms    0.6%    18.00 ms                                                       vPremultiplyData_RGBA8888_CV_sse4_1
12.00 ms    0.4%    12.00 ms                                                       vConvert_ARGB8888ToPlanar8_CV_sse4_1
[...]
295.00 ms   11.0%   0 s                                   ripc_RenderImage
295.00 ms   11.0%   0 s                                    RIPLayerBltImage
294.00 ms   10.9%   0 s                                     ripl_Mark
294.00 ms   10.9%   0 s                                      argb32_image
292.00 ms   10.9%   0 s                                       argb32_image_mark_image
292.00 ms   10.9%   0 s                                        argb32_image_mark_image
292.00 ms   10.9%   292.00 ms                                           argb32_image_mark_argb32


